# Override PAM module options

Tags: pam

Is it possible to override PAM module options for a module that appeared earlier in the PAM stack?

For example, I have `/etc/pam.d/sudo`:

```
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

`common-auth` has:

```
...
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
...
```

I want to add the `nodelay` option to `pam_unix`, but only when using `sudo`, so I can't just add it in `common-auth` because that file is `@include`d by other files too.

Some suboptimal solution I can think of are:

1. Make `common-auth-nodelay` which is copy/pasted with `nodelay`, but that kind of sucks.
2. Add `nodelay` to `common-auth` and then add a delay back using `pam_faildelay.so`. But that isn't fail-safe.

I've read the source code and as far as I can see there's no provision for this, but I just wanted to check in case I missed something.